# Wrong parameter count for bind_param in custom mysqli class

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Trying to generate a custom mysqli class / wrapper with `$this->_mysqli` as a mysqli instance:

```
// Query string generator
private function gen_query($type, $data, $table){
    switch ($type) {
        case 'ins':
            $query = "INSERT INTO " .$table .' ';
            $query .= implode_key($opr= ', ', $data);
            $query .= " VALUES " . value($data);
            break;
        case 'select':
            // yet to generate
        default:
            $query ='';
            break;
    }
    return $query;
}

// Generates bind parameters
private function gen_param($data){
    $_param = "'";
    foreach ($data as $v) {
        $_param .= $this->detect_type($v);
    }
    $_param .= "', ";
    foreach ($data as $k=>$v) {
        if($v == end($data)) {
            $_param .="$$k";
            continue;
        }
        $_param .= "$$k, ";
    }
  return $_param;
}

public function insert( $table, $data ){
    $table  =  $this->_prefix . $table;
    $table = $this->escape($table);
    $query = $this->gen_query('ins', $data, $table);
    $stmt = $this->_mysqli->prepare($query);
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $$key = $value;
    }
    $test = $this->gen_param($data);
    if(!$stmt->bind_param($test)) {
        echo $this->_mysqli->error;
    }
    if($stmt->execute()){
        print 'Success!'.'<br />'; 
    } else {
        die('Error : ('. $this->_mysqli->errno .') '. $this->_mysqli->error);
    }   
}
```

So when user inputs

```
$data = [ 'first_name' => 'foo', 'last_name' => 'bar', 'another_field' => 'blah'];
$db->insert('t1', $data);
```

I get this error:

```
 Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in path\to\class-db.php on line 138
```

This is line 138: `if(!$stmt->bind_param($test))`

Comment: this does not look right `$$key`. Also you are overwriting the `$key` `$value` in the loop by using the same variable names

Comment: I'm trying to generate data pairs for  bind_param so in the above example, the foreach loop should set $first_name = foo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the question was downvoted. Anyways, I got this fixed by referring: [this repo](https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class).

We'll need to get rid of `gen_param`, use an array instead and call using a callback function to get the parameter values right and refer the values.

The code is now:

```
    public function insert( $table, $data ){
    $table  =  $this->_prefix . $table;
    $table = $this->escape($table);
    $this->esc_sql_arr($data);
    $query = $this->gen_query('ins', $data, $table);
    $stmt = $this->_mysqli->prepare($query);
    $this->_bind_param($data);
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'),$this->return_ref($this->bind_arr));
    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "Success!";
    }else{
        die('Error : ('. $this->_mysqli->errno .') '. $this->_mysqli->error);
    }
    $this->reset();
}

private function _bind_param($data){
    foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
        $this->_bind_values($value);
    }
}

private function _bind_values($value) {
    $this->bind_arr[0] .= $this->detect_type($value);
    array_push($this->bind_arr, $value);
}

protected function return_ref(array &$arr)
{
    //Reference in the function arguments are required for HHVM to work
    //https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/5155
    //Referenced data array is required by mysqli since PHP 5.3+
    if (strnatcmp(phpversion(), '5.3') >= 0) {
        $refs = array();
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $refs[$key] = & $arr[$key];
        }
        return $refs;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

The code is nowhere near complete, but this got me started.